# SEO : multiple pages with same content

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

**My question**: Is it bad from a SEO perspective to index different html pages that have (nearly-) identical content?

I am hosting an AngularJS webapp that serves static html pages to search crawlers. I don't want any JS-managed content to be omitted from search engines, so I generated different html files for small variants of the same page.

Example:

- A page that contains 3 tabs will generate 3 html files, one with each
  tab content
- A page with a carousel will generate a html file for each
  instance of the carousel
- A page with a content-rich modal will create an html page for that modal, with the content of the 'master page' grayed out in the background.
- Different languages generate different html files. However, as english is the fallback language, the generated content for 2 different urls is identical when translations are not available.

The result is that there is a lot of "common" content which appears in many different html files served to crawlers.

Is this a recommended approach?